# OleDbDataAdapter empty parameter value

Tags: c#, sql, adapter

I have to make a quite intricate query of the database.What happens if one/more of the parameters was to be empty?Will the SQL ignore it or return an error?How should I handle the empty parameters?I am farely new to SQL.

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE age>? AND children>? ORDER BY children ASC", conection);    
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", age);           
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", number_of_children);
```

How could I handle the query when I have an empty (null content) parameter besides writing a different query for each case?

edit:this is just a simple example, my query has about 5 parameters

Comment: You can use `age != null ? age : value`. `value` is the variable if your `age` is `null`

Comment: Thank you, I think I can fill up the blanks with "defaul value like that.Thank alot!

Answer (score 0):

`x > null` will always bf false.  So if either of your parameter values are null you will get no records back.  You could do something like:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(
    "SELECT ID FROM table WHERE (age> NVL(?,-1)) AND (children> NVL(?,-1) ORDER BY children ASC", conection);    
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", age);           
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", number_of_children);
```

Assuming that `age` and `children` are always non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value and if it is null you can assign `DBNull.Value`

```
if(age>0)
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1",  age);
else
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1",  DBNull.Value);
```